# Definition of Chernoff distance

Tags: hypothesis-testing

In [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01025) the "*Chernoff distance*" between two data sets is defined as:

$$
C D= \frac{1}{2} \alpha_{\mathrm{c}} \alpha_{\mathrm{f}}\left(\mu_{\mathrm{c}}-\mu_{\mathrm{f}}\right)^{ T}\left[\alpha_{\mathrm{c}} \Sigma_{\mathrm{c}}+\alpha_{\mathrm{f}} \Sigma_{\mathrm{f}}\right]^{-1}\left(\mu_{\mathrm{c}}-\mu_{\mathrm{f}}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \log \frac{\left|\alpha_{\mathrm{c}} \Sigma_{\mathrm{c}}+\alpha_{\mathrm{f}} \Sigma_{\mathrm{f}}\right|}{\left|\Sigma_{\mathrm{c}}\right|^{\alpha_{c}}\left|\Sigma_{\mathrm{f}}\right|^{\alpha_{\mathrm{f}}}}$$

where $\alpha$, $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are the "*percentages, means and covariances*" of both groups, and the "*superscripts $T$ and $−1$ refer to the transpose vector and to the inverse of the matrix, respectively*".

The original article referenced as the source of this expression is [Chernoff (1952)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177729330), but I could not find it inside.

I also could not find a proper definition for this distance anywhere else. Is this expression correct? Is it similar to an Anderson-Darling test, or Kullback–Leibler divergence, or Bhattacharyya distance?

Comment: Why is there an integral sign in the exponent?

Comment: It's a typo in the final version of the article, the arXived version shows the proper equation. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Bhattacharya distance for multivariate normal distributions, see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance), when the factors $\alpha =1/2$.

As that distance is
$$
B= \int \sqrt{f g} dx
$$
I speculate that the Chernoff distance is 
$$
\int f^\alpha g^{1-\alpha} dx
$$
and that this formulae for multivariate normals would give us your expression.

Furthermore if the covariance matrixes are equal, it reduces to a distance that is equivalent to the Mahalanoblis distance

Comment: You are right, it does look almost exactly like the Bhattacharyya distance for multivariate normal distributions. But still, where did the authors got this expression as the "*Chernoff distance*"?